# javascript random number from array returns a single letter/symbol

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have some code that I need to choose a random string from the array but it keeps returning a single letter or number. How can this be fixed?

```html
<html>
    <script>
        var name = ["Yayek", "Vozarut", "Gezex", "Jujax", "Luvac", "Merea", "Qokac", "Doeimit", "Qeneh", "Pezog", "Iakej", "Zihec", "Auziyeb", "Aehug", "Buyob", "Jojuxuk", "Dopix", "Yenacah", "Rigun", "Bihey", "Goziiig", "Oiqik", "Vubarel", "Lokiuul", "Gizah", "Susofic", "Navulaj", "Qioaoeo", "Aeyom", "Aibul", "Oekojem", "Aeauvuu", "Goeuyoa", "Pihoa", "Noyikaw", "Soaeuip", "Diyufak", "Fewuy", "Uaqid", "Aisizeo", "Mewupen", "Rinel", "Cavawax", "Aepon", "Wutoq", "Ousoyan", "Jaban", "Pizoq", "Eeyawok", "Uuaub", "Lalajac", "Gaeaj", "Lieau", "Ouzuous", "Pevux", "Powig", "Pever", "Woqekie", "Sobukoe", "Vomab", "Eirinek", "Eumeb", "Raficiw", "Dezuw", "Niqeoin", "Yamet", "Ouaie", "Ouguk", "Galut", "Oaouu", "Jaaoron", "Nioekuu", "Fevuv", "Yofit", "Caaeyox", "Hapis", "Winiial", "Miyie", "Pigev", "Yujioei", "Vuxon", "Eirioul", "Lukadux", "Kadec", "Qocewec", "Kitobot", "Yedel", "Vobojox", "Vovop", "Cimicak", "Ruoenur", "Liyos", "Einiben", "Pawosoj", "Limai", "Dotuiaa", "Zuwogin", "Zaxiv", "Aojuo", "Puuutoe", "Xusaqae", "Raxiy", "Ouxab", "Zalud", "Dowutoh", "Aitoiai", "Leloban", "Jiiow", "Sewek", "Dokeqox", "Lapuree", "Maded", "Wowuk", "Zouov", "Wonaeox", "Kodineo", "Gowes", "Neziy"];
        var cards = [{
            key: 'name',
            data: name
        }];
        var c1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
        alert(cards[c1].data);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `rc1`. You're indexing into `data` which is a string. Just do `cards[c1].data`

Comment: Yes that does stop it from alerting a single letter. But, it now alerts the entire array.

Comment: Looks like it should be `cards[0].data[c1]`? But really, what are you trying to do?

Comment: `data` is an array of strings.  You're issue is that you're indexing into an into `cards` incorrectly.  You should need to access it like `cards[0]['data'][rc1]`

also:
`var rc1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards[0]['data'].length)`

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to get a random card from a random deck?

Comment: When I run your code it alerts the whole array, not a single letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below It works fine :

HTML Code:

```
 <input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Click It" onclick="randomfunction()"/>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function randomfunction(){
var name = ["Yayek", "Vozarut", "Gezex", "Jujax", "Luvac", "Merea", "Qokac", "Doeimit", "Qeneh", "Pezog", "Iakej", "Zihec", "Auziyeb", "Aehug", "Buyob", "Jojuxuk", "Dopix", "Yenacah", "Rigun", "Bihey", "Goziiig", "Oiqik", "Vubarel", "Lokiuul", "Gizah", "Susofic", "Navulaj", "Qioaoeo", "Aeyom", "Aibul", "Oekojem", "Aeauvuu", "Goeuyoa", "Pihoa", "Noyikaw", "Soaeuip", "Diyufak", "Fewuy", "Uaqid", "Aisizeo", "Mewupen", "Rinel", "Cavawax", "Aepon", "Wutoq", "Ousoyan", "Jaban", "Pizoq", "Eeyawok", "Uuaub", "Lalajac", "Gaeaj", "Lieau", "Ouzuous", "Pevux", "Powig", "Pever", "Woqekie", "Sobukoe", "Vomab", "Eirinek", "Eumeb", "Raficiw", "Dezuw", "Niqeoin", "Yamet", "Ouaie", "Ouguk", "Galut", "Oaouu", "Jaaoron", "Nioekuu", "Fevuv", "Yofit", "Caaeyox", "Hapis", "Winiial", "Miyie", "Pigev", "Yujioei", "Vuxon", "Eirioul", "Lukadux", "Kadec", "Qocewec", "Kitobot", "Yedel", "Vobojox", "Vovop", "Cimicak", "Ruoenur", "Liyos", "Einiben", "Pawosoj", "Limai", "Dotuiaa", "Zuwogin", "Zaxiv", "Aojuo", "Puuutoe", "Xusaqae", "Raxiy", "Ouxab", "Zalud", "Dowutoh", "Aitoiai", "Leloban", "Jiiow", "Sewek", "Dokeqox", "Lapuree", "Maded", "Wowuk", "Zouov", "Wonaeox", "Kodineo", "Gowes", "Neziy"]
var cards = [{
  key: 'name',
  data: name
}];
var c1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
var rc1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards[c1].data.length);
alert(cards[c1].data[rc1]);
}
```

Comment: this still only alerts one letter

Answer (score 0):

You end up with this `cards` structure:

```
var cards = [
            |     {
            |         key: 'name',
            |        data: [
            |           0 : Yayek,
            |           1 : Vozarut,
            |           etc...
            |     ?
            |     |
    cards   [c1].data
```

Note how your array `data` reference points at nothing. You don't have an array of arrays, you have an array containing an object, which contains a sub-array, and THAT sub-array contains your name data.

You should have

```
cards[0].data[1] -> Vazarut
```

Comment: it then alerts 'A'

Comment: then do a `console.log(cards)` and follow the rabbit down the hole.